# Usage of brackets for missing or unclear transcription

Tags: punctuation

I have for many year wondered what is missing when I read sentences like

> David Canton, the Education Department spokesman, stated: 
>   “(It) shouldn’t have happened. (C)ommon sense should prevail.”

I can understand that (It) might mean mean that the transcriber did not hear the "It" - perhaps the person omitted the word, but "(C)ommon"?

Would that mean that the recording might have some noise drowning the "C" out and the transcriber could not hear it or how do you interpret this?

Comment: I reckon those should be square brackets.

Comment: That is what I normally see too.

Comment: Actually the duplicate answer only incidentally answers my question since I asked _what do they mean_ and not _how do I use them_ :) I cannot delete it now anyway due to the answer

Comment: Still baffles me when I get a downvote without a comment at this site. It is so rude and non-constructive.

Comment: Wasn't me. And yes, you might want this question instead: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110582/bracketed-capital-letter

Comment: "Please stop asking bracketed questions" - Mine was in parenthesis ;)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this sense "(It)" is used to replace something else that was said, so that the small segment of speech makes sense.  So, the original might have read, "This incidence of inadequate teaching resources was avoidable and shouldn't have happened".

"(C)" is used to replace a similar section, and also replaces the original lower case "c" with an upper case "C".  The original might have read, "And with the benefit of my many years in the Education Department, I would expect that common sense should prevail".

Comment: Right. now it makes more sense

Comment: Good suggestions. Of course, there is a moral duty on the quoter not to twist the sense from perhaps "This incidence of inadequate teaching resources was unavoidable and no one claimed that the situation shouldn't have happened. But on the other hand, few would expect that common sense should prevail".

Comment: I would have expected ellipsis if things had been left out.